# How to pass parameters in url using php page

Tags: php

here i am trying to pass the id as parameter for next page using php.

I am retrieving values from database and i have id as a primary key. i want to pass the id for next page. but when i pass the parameter through URL its not appearing on url. how can i do this?

here is what i have done.

```
echo "<a href='product-des.php?'". $row["product_id"].">";
```

here the URL is visible till.php but i am not able to see any id after that.

what am i doing wrong here... how can i do this?

Comment: `?'"` Single quote is a bit early

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks for noticing that.... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass parameter

```
echo '<a href="product-des.php?pro_id='. $row["product_id"].'">';
```

To get parameter:

```
echo $_GET['pro_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

this

```
echo "<a href='product-des.php?'". $row["product_id"].">";
```

should be like this

```
echo "<a href='product-des.php?product_id=".$row['product_id']'>."'" >Product Name</a>";
```

try this